# Dynamically creating layout on swipe

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm creating a "calendar viewer" type of functionality for my application (I'm really surprised there is no 'local calendar' widget in Android without the need for Google Calendar.)

I've got a basic view in place which displays the current month inside a TableLayout, showing each day number under its respective named day. I want to take this further to allow the user to swipe left or right to go forwards/back a month. This would then require the UI to be rebuilt.

What's the most efficient way to accomplish this? Currently I'm dynamically creating the first screen in the 'onCreate' method of my Activity, so I was thinking of abstracting away the creation of the UI and to simply rebuild the screen upon swipe, just from a different starting month - so I'd be deleting the current month's views.

However, I wonder if that would result in bloat somehow - having to add and remove many layout elements each time upon swipe.

Comment: Is there any reason you do not want to use viewpager or something similar?

Comment: There is android CalendarView http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html

Comment: are you looking for something similar to this http://cdn.makeagif.com/media/12-30-2015/JSx5zZ.gif

Comment: @sector11 - yes, that's great! I have no idea how I didn't manage to find this widget, my Google-fu has failed :(

Comment: @StevenSproat  that thing is not completely Android CalendarView i made some customization using GridView :D

Comment: In regards to the original question, is recreating he UI on each 'swipe' going to be an expensive operation? I'm interested in developing something myself  for the learning experience - playing about with the CalendarView, it seems that the month's days are shown in a scrollable list. I can't tell if the UI's being re-built as I swipe around, changing the months